# Why does a search for "extra dependency" give no results?

Tags: bug, searching

There is [Why does apt think it needs this extra dependency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138484/why-does-apt-think-it-needs-this-extra-dependency), but when I search for  "extra dependency" (with quotes) the search returns "0 Results".

Comment: Because the search does not use quotes.

Comment: @FEichinger You aren't entirely right.  The tips for search [specifically mention using quotes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8128411#8128411).

Comment: Indeed. And apparently it does work ... sometimes (might be related to the change in search engine, though). Weeeeeeird.

Comment: Okay, I think we found it: The exact/quote syntax matches only *full words*: "extra dependency?" works, "xtra dependency?" and "extra dependency" fail.

Comment: "Full words" as in "split by spaces" ;)

Comment: Also: Related MSO report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167764/exact-search-syntax-matches-only-full-words